# software pattern- what is this?

Tags: c#, templates, generics, c++-cli

Is this similar to some software design pattern you may know?

I have an interface:

```
public interface IA {
}
```

and its child class which is sealed:

```
sealed public class A: IA {
}
```

Now that I have another template class `B` in which I would like to use an object of type `A` in place of `T` type:

```
template<class T>
public class B {
    T a;
    IA pa;

    B() {

    }
}
```

However, the constructor of `A` does not allow me to specify the template as `B<A>` and the error states that `A` is *sealed*, `A` can't be used in the template.

In order to solve this problem, I create another class:

```
public class C {
    A a;

    A GetA() {
        return a;
    }
}
```

then rewrite the template class `B`:

```
template<class T>
public class B {
    C c;
    IA pa;

    B() {
        // initialize c=new C();
        // initialize pa=c.GetA();
    }
}
```

I think my class hierarchy has some flaw, I would like it to be templatized or generic, but the introduction of a class like `C` doesn't seem to sustain what I am working with anymore.

What if I have more classes `X`, `Y` and `Z`, etc., that also implement `IA` interface?

---

**EDIT**

My program now works fine, I just don't know if I applied any pattern as above. And that once I have another class `X`:

```
public class X: IA {
}
```

and in order to use this `X` as a parameter for `B<X>`, I have to add a new definition of *X's representative class* as

```
public class RX {
    X x;

    RX() {
        x=new X();
    }

    X GetX() {
        return x;
    }
}
```

So I must also rewrite the class B as:

```
template<class T>
public class B {
    C c;
    RX x;
    IA pa;

    B() {
        // initialize c=new C();
        // initialize pa=c.GetA();;
        // if parameter X is used 
        // pa=x.GetX();
    }
}
```

You see, it doesn't look neat.

Comment: `template` in C#? that's new.

Comment: What is it you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: :D thank you, I'm messed up not knowing what should I write there to make this question, if I wrote it as `generic` then it becomes c++.net/cli which no one really cares about these days.

Comment: I removed the C# tag and replaced it with C++.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead this isn't C++...

Comment: @Pubby Is the OP asking for C# advice or C++? It appears to be a mixture. Either way, the code in question appears to represent the "prefer composition over inheritance" approach.. which is fine.

Comment: `public class` is not legal nor would it make any sense in C++.  `c=new C()` wouldn't compile because `c` is not a `C*`.  This code/question makes no sense.

Comment: Three comments from 20k+ users that this question makes no sense, but no close votes thus far. Strange. And people say that questions get closed overzealously...

Comment: `template<class T>` is the main reason I changed the tag. I'm aware that `public class` is not valid in vanilla C++.. however I figured this was probably C++.NET.. which I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: Thank you, I added an edit part to clarify what I would like to know. Please forget the modifiers or any keywords that are specific to some languages. I would like to write a C++ and C#'s common ancestor language so that no arguments for their differences are brought up. I once thought about abstract algebra used to describe type systems but bleh blah bloh I am no expert to get even what a single term in there actually means...

Comment: generics in C++ and C# are very different... It would be much easier for everyone if you stick with just one and provide sample that compiles (and preferably use type `T` passed as template type)...

Comment: Are you the C++ guy that beats its wife C# ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess it's called [proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern).